# ReactNative-What's an easy way to implement PageView analytics across all pages?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio-app-center

I am implementing Microsoft's [AppCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/analytics/react-native) for Crashalytics and Analytics. In Native development, I am able to add two lines of code and it adds pageview analytics (track each time a page is viewed) to every page in the app. I am curious to know if there's an easy way I can do it in a React Native app as well. This is what it looks like on native:

In native iOS, I just create a BaseViewController and make sure every ViewController inherits from that class. And then in the ViewDidLoad of the BaseViewController I add something like the line below.

And in native Android, I just create a BaseFragment and make sure every Fragment inherits from that class. And then in the OnCreate of the BaseFragment I add something like the line below:

```
Analytics.TrackEvent("PageView: " + this.GetType().Name)
```

How can I implement something similar on React Native? I am guessing that since I am using a  across all pages, I could somehow create a BaseSafeAreaView that I can then add similar analytics code in the UseEffect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I am using react-navigation, I was able to [use this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-tracking/) with my NavigationContainer so I didn't need any base class

```
...
export default () => {
  const navigationRef = useNavigationContainerRef();
  const routeNameRef = useRef();

  return (
    <NavigationContainer
      ref={navigationRef}
      onReady={() => {
        routeNameRef.current = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;
      }}
      onStateChange={async () => {
        const previousRouteName = routeNameRef.current;
        const currentRouteName = navigationRef.getCurrentRoute().name;

        if (previousRouteName !== currentRouteName) {
          await Analytics.trackEvent('PageView: ' + currentRouteName);
        }
        routeNameRef.current = currentRouteName;
      }}
    >
...
```

Answer (score 1):

How about [Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/) ? You can implement a fully blown analytic solution.

They have a [react native integration](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/react-native-quickstart)

segment is also great. They provide support for [react native integration] as well. You can [integrate segment with mixpanel](https://developer.mixpanel.com/docs/segment) if necessary.

Firebase analytics is also a good solution. This can be done with [rnfirebase analytics package](https://rnfirebase.io/analytics/usage)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I was able to figure it out, I just updated my answer :)